# Even if the div condition is not satisfied it is executing the code inside div

Tags: angularjs

Even if the div condition is not satisfied it is executing the code inside div.

```
 <div ng-if = "1==11">
                            nishant
                                    <td><a href="indexForm.jsp?id={{x.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a></td>

                            </div>
```

Here in the code the ng-if is not satisfied, so it need not to go through the div, but it is not printing "nishant" but executing .Kindly, help me why it is executing .

Comment: It is executing <td> even if ng-if is not satisfied.Help me out why it is happening.

Comment: i don't see any problem here its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/tb9hzqu3/

Comment: can you please explain  "but it is not printing "nishant" but executing "

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be

```
 <div  ng-if = "1!==11">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 <div  ng-if = "1==11">
   nishant
     <td><a href="indexForm.jsp?id={{x.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a></td>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: See it is working fine for text nishant. But it is executing <td> tag even if ng-if is not satisfied.One <td> tag is there in the code, that one getting executed irrespective of the condition.

Comment: Where? in the demo it is not. check the demo

Comment: See in my code also, it is working fine for text "nishant". But my concern is if ng-if is not satisfied so why it is going inside the div tag for me, and executing <td> tag.

Comment: did you check the demo? it is not going inside the div at all

Comment: In my code it is going inside, is it because i am using ng-repeat in the code for populating the table?

Comment: where have you placed ng-repeat? create a jsfiddle

Comment: @Sajeetharan  did you notice the line in the question "but it is not printing "nishant" but executing" do you understand what he is trying to ask?

Comment: @jitender executing what?

Comment: @Sajeetharan same thing i am trying to understand see my comment on the question i think we should not answer before properly understanding the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div ng-if = "1==11">
                        nishant False Condition
                                <td><a href="indexForm.jsp?id={{x.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a></td>

                        </div>
         <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div ng-if = "1!==11">
                        nishant true condition
                                <td><a href="indexForm.jsp?id={{x.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a></td>

                        </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with your controller I think there's no problem with this code as you can see.Please check your console for errors

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine for me as well.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-if="1==11">
        nishant
        <td>
            <a href="indexForm.jsp?id={{x.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
        </td>
    </div>
    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.x = {
                id: 1,
                name: 'A'
            };
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You said even though the condition is not getting satisfied, it is executing the div block? Could you please explain what do you mean by executing?

Here condition is not getting satisfied, so will remove that div tag completely from the DOM. You can read more about ngIf on this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).